# Adding table reference constraints after table creation MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, many-to-many

I've got two tables representing interests and products. I'm implementing a many_many relationship between them. When I created the tables I neglected to create table constraints to ensure the assignment table's records are deleted if either product or interest records are deleted.

**Interests Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `interests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `interest` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=62 ;
```

**Products Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=65 ;
```

**Assignment Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `interest_product_assignment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `interest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `product` (`product_id`),
  KEY `interest` (`interest_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

My attempt to add this constraint in appears unsuccessful-

```
ALTER TABLE `interest_product_assignment` ADD CONSTRAINT `product` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE `interest_product_assignment` ADD CONSTRAINT `interest` FOREIGN KEY (`interest_id`) REFERENCES `interest` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

When I delete product records, corresponding assignment records aren't deleted.

Some questions on this:

1. Is this the correct syntax for this kind of constraint?
2. Does it matter that I've not added these constraints upon creating the
   tables or that I've already got data in the tables?
3. Where in PHPMyADMIN can I see if my constraints were successfully added? I can't seem to find reference to them anywhere, prompting me to think PHPMyADMIN ignored my constraint without throwing an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding foreign key does not give warning/error on MyISAM tables but it is not supported.

You would need to change MyISAM to InnoDB before creating the foreign keys and it will work perfectly fine.

From official MySQL manual:

> At a later stage, foreign key constraints will be implemented for
>   MyISAM tables as well

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html